# In Listview one row in bigger in size

Tags: android, listview

In my listview one row was in bigger in size.

1. Initially all are in same width and height
2. After scrolling some time one row become bigger (see in below image)
   now in Entertainment
3. Scrolling again that Gaming will become bigger

How to resolve?

[image]

Comment: trim the string before set it to text view.

Comment: Can you post the layout for the items and the code for the adapter please ?

Comment: Can you post some of your code ?

Comment: May be the problem lies in getview() of your adapter class..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your items are varying in height a little bit.

One of the standard things to do for a `ListView` is to use the Android Attribute `listPreferredItemHeight` which will provide a preferred item height for the device.

So. Your layout for the list items would look something like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
/>
```

This will give you a single TextView for each item, with the preferred system height.